# Split column into multiple rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using sparkml and I have data as below in a CSV.  The first is a movie name and the following values are various ratings received.  The number of ratings would differ.

E.g.
Titanic,9,10,8,6,9
Frozen,8,8,8
Cars,6,7,8,5

I want them as 
Titanic,9
Titanic,10
Titanic,8
Titanic,6
Frozen,8
Frozen,8
Frozen,8
Cars,6
Cars,7
Cars,8
Cars,5

Any idea how to go about this.
I looked at Explode functionality, but it was helping me in scenario where the delimiter was different like: Titanic,|9|10|8|6|9.  Here delimiter is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of ratings can differ for each movie you should read you data as a textFile, not a CSV. Assuming you get a DataFrame containing each line of the file

```
val df = Seq(
  "Titanic,9,10,8,6,9",
  "Frozen,8,8,8",
  "Cars,6,7,8,5"
).toDF("line")
```

Using a simple UDF split each line in two parts, the movie and the ratings. By setting the limit parameter to `2` we ensure to split only at the first delimiter `,`

```
val splitLine = udf { s : String => s.split(",", 2) }
```

And then split and explode the ratings

```
df.withColumn("mr", splitLine($"line"))
  .select(
    $"mr"(0).as("movie"), 
    explode(split($"mr"(1), ",")).as("rating")
  )
```

Which gives the expected output

```
+-------+------+
|  movie|rating|
+-------+------+
|Titanic|     9|
|Titanic|    10|
|Titanic|     8|
|Titanic|     6|
|Titanic|     9|
| Frozen|     8|
| Frozen|     8|
| Frozen|     8|
|   Cars|     6|
|   Cars|     7|
|   Cars|     8|
|   Cars|     5|
+-------+------+
```